# Need ready-made front end for Google TTS

Tags: macos, user-interface, web-frontend, google-text-to-speech

I would like to run some text through Google's TTS engine and create an audio file. The purpose is to create a female English voiceover for an MVP explainer video, as my own voice and pronunciation isn't fit for this.

I've gone through Google's account and billing setup, I guess I now have access to their API. But I don't have a front end / user interface.

Is there something available that I could connect to the API? Either web-based or for MacOS? I'm not a developer so building it myself is not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Google Text-to-Speech` [console](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-console) or the [command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-api). These interfaces are user-friendly and do not need a developer-level skill.

You can also check this similar Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61948764/google-text-tospeech-getting-the-audio-file-in-front-end) which showed how to create a front-end by creating a simple code.

Comment: Thanks Astrid. I succeeded in enabling the TTS API but I got so confused by configuration procedure and scared by the different pricing levels (microcents per milliseconds to €2700 per month) that I'm afraid I'll click the wrong option and get charged a month's wages.

Comment: Maybe there's a commercial service that created a front-end service for me, with a more transparent pricing model?